# Jquery selection, adding id just to make selection easier, good or not?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, selection

I just would like to ask you if It's good or not to add IDs on some HTML elements just to make their selection easier. Instead of using all the methods available to traverse the dom in Jquery for exemple.

For sure, It makes the HTML a bit heavier as I add IDs on more elements, but is there anything else bad with this practice ?

Thank you,

Comment: id selectors are fastest so there is no issues with this. Also you can go with the parent/child selectors too.

Comment: As long are the ids are unique, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantages**

- It's faster, jQuery "#id" selector use the native document.getElementById. and the uniqueness of an ID make it really fast (it must implement an BST I guess)
- Your code is cleaner. When I read code I prefer $("#mycustomItem") rather than $"(div ul li:eq(3)"). so you will ba able to maintain your code easily and find bug quickly

**Disadvantages**

- HTML heavier. I don't think and id will make your file significantly heavier. If you use compression like gzip you won't be able to notice the difference even for a high number of elements
- Server-side logic more complicated : if you generate id's you will make to compute them on server-side, so it will increase the complexity of your code. In most of the case this complexity added will be  more important than the complexity you remove on the client size.

**Conclusion**

If you can add id's use them but if it increase the complexity on your server side logic don't do it. The speed you earn will not worth the time/complexity you spend generating the id on server-side.

Comment: Pefect answer, I wanted to be sure of things I was doing. Thank you.